# Remove the text shadow from the search field

Tags: bug, design, search

Today, I've noticed that the search field on Sec.SE contains a shadow. This shadow makes the text a bit blurry, and harder to read:

- With text shadow:
  <sub>[image: with shadow]</sub>
- Without shadow:
  <sub>[image: without shadow]</sub>

Can this text shadow be removed?